# ChartJs Legend OnClick Update Datasets

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm new to ChartJs and I want your help please, as you can see I have a mixed chart in the image below, what I want to happen is to; **Update both** of my **Line One** and  **Line Two** datasets dynamically when I clicked either **Bar One** and **Bar Two**. Is there a tooltip should I use here?

Output : https://jsfiddle.net/juvielonelagos/qjav2gmL/1/

```
 const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

      new Chart(ctx, {
        data: {
          datasets: [
            {
              type: "line",
              label: "Line One",
              data: [10, 30, 21, 11],
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              borderColor: "blue",
            },
            {
              type: "line",
              label: "Line Two",
              data: [20, 24, 13, 30],
              backgroundColor: "red",
              borderColor: "red",
            },
            {
              type: "bar",
              label: "Bar One",
              data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
              backgroundColor: "orange",
            },
            {
              type: "bar",
              label: "Bar Two",
              data: [10, 30, 20, 13],
              backgroundColor: "purple",
            },
          ],
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April"],
        },
      });

      document.getElementById("red").style.back;
```

[image]